# Auto Set echo value base on value from datetime

Tags: php, mysql

How do i set the value of echo **$row['$d'];** to auto to follow datetime. For example if date = Apr so the value inside echo should be $row['**Apr**']; without change manualy.

```
    <?php 
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
$today = strtotime("today");
$d=strtotime("-1 Month");
include("config/view-graph.php"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM settings where id = '1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql); if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo date("M", $d). "<br>";
    echo $row['Apr'];
 } } else { echo "0 results"; } $conn->close(); ?>
```

Comment: you need ajax to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign it to a variable and use it:-

```
$day_name =date("M", $d). "<br>";
echo $row[$day_name];
```